# How do I redirect cucumber failed scenarios to stderr?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Unluckily it seems that everything goes to stdout...

Comment: It's outputting test failures, not an error that happened while running Cucumber itself, so it wouldn't have been correct to send it to stderr.

Comment: I agree the concept of 'error' in a testing tool is more complicated than normal... but consider this: when some features/tests are failing cucumber or rspec exit to the shell with a '1' value. That signals an 'error' to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The cucumber formatters take a single IO object, which will either be a file if you specify the `--out` option on the command line, or `STDOUT` if it is the last or only formatter specified.

Cucumber scenarios tend to fail partially, with the first few steps passing before a failure occurs, so you'd have to consider exactly what information you'd want to be written to STDOUT.

You could certainly create a custom cucumber formatter that wrote different bits of information to different IO streams, it's fairly easy to see how they work by looking at the built-in formatters.  As Andrew Marshall pointed out in the comments though, it's not really the correct use of stderr.

Comment: I posted a comment to the previous answer that applies here too: why cucumber returns '1' to the shell when failing some features?

Comment: Interesting point, one that's bitten me recently because I was trying to figure out how to differentiate between a cucumber run that *failed to execute properly* (i.e. crashed during startup), and one that ran successfully but had failing tests - it didn't really seem possible!  But to answer your question, it's standard for testing tools to return a non-zero exit code when tests fail, it's how build runners detect the failed tests and know whether to fail the build or not.

Comment: Exactly. The genesis of my question comes from a bunch of scripts I wrote for a continuous integration bot. Obviously I send an email to the devs when cucumber exit with a '1' value. What I wanted to do was to filter out non-relevant output to send devs infos about failing scenarios only.

[Regarding 'cucumber crashes' it would be nice to have an exit value different from 0 or 1 (not to break CI tools) or even better to return a value of '1' for crashes and another non-zero value for failing scenarios. But that's another story.] Thanks for your answers anyway.